# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Model' issues in Training Images

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

**I am trying to do a program with the help of some resources. Suddenly, I got an import error.**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import h5py
#import dlib
from imutils import face_utils
from keras.models import load_model
import sys
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
#from keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import backend as K 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from Model import model
from model.Model import model
from keras import callbacks
```

> **When I run the above program, I got the following error about import Model**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8cbfce6231b9> in <module>
     18 from keras import backend as K
     19 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
---> 20 from Model import model
     21 from model.Model import model
     22 from keras import callbacks

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Model'
```

I am trying to solve a lot of times but I failed to solve this issue.

Comment: Model is not a well known package, you need to tell us what package this is, we cannot really guess. It seems to be specific to your code.

Comment: The error will resolve if you simply remove both these code lines `from Model import model` , `from model.Model import model` which are causing error. There is no Module available with this name. Instead of that you can use `from tensorflow.keras import Model` to import the Model in your code. Please let us know if issue still persists.